# Implement video call using phone masking Android

Tags: android, video, sip

I want to implement video calling in my android application using phone masking,i referred a lot of links in google but i didn't get it ,

please any one give a sample projects or referral links ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to find sample projects or referral links. That's what a search engine is for.

Answer (score 0):

First I would ask you to **have a look at this** [Official Google Docs for getting started with NATIVE webRTC lib in android](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1idl_NYQhllFEFqkGQOLv8KBK8M3EVzyvxnKkHl4SuM8/edit)

once you understand the basics from those docs **have a look at working example** made available by pubnub that uses same native webRTC library for a sample video chat app. They have web interface as well that lets you make calls from desktop to android. This is a good learning source for someone who wants to try Video Chat using native webRTC android support.

[Click here for PubNub example using native android webRTC lib](https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-tutorial)